# xpath query on a html table always returns empty string in python

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, lxml

here's the python code of what i've tried:

```
from lxml import html
import requests


page = requests.get('http://www.rsssf.com/tablese/eng2017det.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
print(tree.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]//text()'))
```

I'm always getting my output as []
I have also checked the html page, the URL isn't broken

Comment: Note that `lxml.html` supports XPath 1.0 only, so XPath 2.0 tag was redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `tbody` tag in your XPath. Note that developer might skip this tag, so it will be added automatically by browser while page rendering.

Simply try

```
print(tree.xpath('/html/body/table//tr[2]//text()'))
```

or

```
print([i for i in tree.xpath('/html/body/table//tr[2]//text()') if i.strip()])
```

to avoid printing new line characters

Comment: thanks. It helped. Any clue on how to iterate all the tr tags from first to last?

Comment: Just remove index to get list of table rows: `for row in tree.xpath('/html/body/table//tr'): print(row.text_content())`